# Autocomplete using annotations for Rails scope in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Hi I am using RubyMine 2016.2.4 , Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.1.7
And I would like to have auto complete after using a scope
I read this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/using-annotations.html
But it does not have an example for using scopes.
I tried something like this in my Product Model:

```
# @!method price_range(min,max)
#   @return [Product]
scope :price_range, ->(min,max) { where(price: (min..max)) }
```

but this Product.price_range(30,40) does not give the the code suggestions for Product. Do you have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck using the alternative notation for scopes and using `Product::self`:

```
# @return [Product::self]
def self.price_range(min,max)
  where(price: (min..max))
end
```

Comment: Can't edit my answers yet, but:

    # @return [Product]

also works

Comment: It works but it is just a static method. not a scope

Comment: Scope is just syntactic sugar:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope